# Does buying models and fish do anything except waste my money?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I'm just wondering if buying the models and fish on the Citadel will get me anything, except a hole in my virtual budget of Spectre.

Comment: Scepter? Did you mean "Shepard" or are you referencing something else entirely?

Comment: Spectres. My brain just had a lag.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Other than giving you the hottest Captain's Cabin in Citadel Space, no, purchasing these items will not do anything additional for you.